# Override a java method that expects a double array

Tags: java, scala

Say I define the following java interface:

```
public interface A
{
  public Double[] x();
}
```

And then try to implement it in scala as follows:

```
class B extends A {
  val v: Array[Double] = Array(2.3, 6.7)
  override def x() = v
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[scala.Double]
[error]  required: Array[java.lang.Double]
[error]     override def x() = v
```

Can someone tell me the recommended way to automatically convert this array?

Thanks
Des

Comment: Is the array big enough and accessed enough for performance to be a concern?  Also, your comment below is important - you "must" use "pure Scala".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't convert it automatically. The issue is that `Double` in Java means the class `java.lang.Double` (while in Scala it means `scala.Double` which is mostly the same as `double` in Java), and so the overriding method *has* to return `Array[java.lang.Double]`. If you have an `Array[Double]`, you can convert it using `map`:

```
val v: Array[Double] = ...
val v1 = v.map(java.lang.Double.valueOf(_)) // valueOf converts Double into java.lang.Double
```

You *could* make this conversion implicit:

```
implicit def wrapDoubleArray(arr: Array[Double]): Array[java.lang.Double] =
  arr.map(java.lang.Double.valueOf(_))
```

but this is a bad idea in most circumstances.

Comment: Why is the implicit conversion usually a bad idea?

Comment: 1. You may end up having to add similar conversions for arrays of other primitive wrapper types (i.e. `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Long`, etc.), for types other than `Array` (`List`, `Seq`, `Map` and so on).

Comment: 2. This conversion isn't trivial (it has to actually create the new array and fill it) and making it implicit hides the cost.

Comment: 3. If one of the arrays is changed, it won't affect the other. Since they look like one array, this may surprise the users.

Answer (score 2):

If the type of `v` must be `Array[scala.Double]`, then perhaps you should consider performing the conversion yourself in the overridden method:

```scala
class B extends A {
  val v: Array[Double] = Array(2.3, 6.7)

  override def x(): Array[java.lang.Double] = {
    v map { java.lang.Double.valueOf(_) }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

```
class B extends A {
  val v: Array[java.lang.Double] = Array(2.3D, 6.7D)
  override def x() = v
}
```

Comment: No afraid not, v should to be a pure scala type.